TailwindCSS media breakpoints not working on Safari
I am trying to make a simple side navbar that changes size based on browser size. No matter what class is used with a media breakpoint it does not work. I also tried modifying the tailwind config file and it still did not work. However, as soon as I went to test on Chrome instead of Safari the breakpoints are working. What could I be missing in either my styling, tailwind config, or even Safari config that is keeping the breakpoints from working?
I tried to have a side navbar that changes size based on the browser width. No media breakpoints work while testing in Safari, but they do once moving to Chrome.
<div className="flex flex-row">
  <div className="min-w-16 max-w-16 md:min-w-64 md:max-w-64">
    {...side navbar content}
  </div>
  {...other content}
</div>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Having a similar issue here with tailwind css class breakpoints not working in Safari only.
